# SilverLight 4 DataGrid & MVVM: Using SelectionChanged trigger to check checkbox, but NotifyPropertyChanged causes crash

Tags: mvvm, silverlight-4.0, datagrid, inotifypropertychanged

I have a DataGridCheckBoxColumn in my DataGrid which is to indicate the rows the user has selected. I want the checkboxes to be checked/unchecked with a single click. Making the column editable (i.e. IsReadOnly="False") means the user has to click twice (first click just selects the row, 2nd click changes the checkbox), so I decided to set/clear the property the column is bound to in the view model code in response to the SelectionChanged trigger firing.

Setting/clearing the property works fine, however as soon as I call NotifyPropertyChanged("name of collection the grid is bound to") to get the view to show the change, this causes the SelectionChanged trigger to fire again. This loops about 10 times until an exception is thrown.

If I remove the call to NotifyPropertyChanged, the SelectionChanged trigger fires once, but of course I don't see any change in the UI. The collection is a PagedCollectionView if this makes any difference.

How can I get this to work? Note - I am using MVVM pattern, so everything is done with bindings to View Model (no code behind).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a very simple solution that doesn't involve triggers or code behind. See: [Silverlight single-click checkbox DataGrid columns](http://crmvoyager.wordpress.com/2010/11/01/silverlight-single-click-checkbox-datagrid-columns/)

It seems to work by using a column template, but only providing the CellEditingTemplate and no CellTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a infinite loop by design.

but try using the selectionchanging instead of selectionchanged,

or put a isloading flag in your viewmodel and dont call the inotify if the isloading is true

Comment: There is no selectionchanged trigger unfortunately.